# Do objects passed into methods need to be returned to be changed?

Tags: java, oop, object

If I pass a object into a method and I change that object in that method will it keep its changes?
I'm not sure if I've worded this right so I'll give an example:

```
public void methodThatChangesX(ClassWithVariableX var) {
    var.x = 5;
}

ExampleClass var = new ExampleClass(); 
//ExampleClass's x's default is 6

methodThatChangesX(var);

System.out.println("x = " + var.x);
```

Would var's x be 5 or 6? Is there a reason for this?

Answer (score 4):

The value would be 5, but this behaviour applies only to *class types*.
If you pass an argument of a *primitive type* (such as an `int`), you will be dealing with a copy inside the method.

In fact, even the class-type argument that is passed in is really only *a new reference to the same object*, so if instead of `var.x = something` you said `var = something`, that would not end up changing the caller's `var`.

ETA: Some in-depth explanations of what is really going on there:

- [Is Java “pass-by-reference” or “pass-by-value”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)
- [Parameter passing in Java - by reference or by value?](http://jonskeet.uk/java/passing.html)

Comment: How can you say that the value will be 6? You said it your self that "the class-type argument that is passed in is really only a new reference to the same object" in which case the value of `var.x` **will** change as long as you pass `var` it self so the answer is 5.

Comment: The  value of `var.x` will be 5. Downvoting as it is a wrong answer.

Comment: I had misread the question as 5 being the "default" and 6 being the new value, while it had actually been asked the other way around. Sorry about that - edited now to correct the digit. The explanation given in the answer is however correct.

Comment: @hemflit I didnt downvote, but that 6 there really triggered a swift response since the answer was really misleading. +1 for the edit

Comment: Thank you @DimaMaligin, the answer was definitely misleading that way, and your reaction was 100% justified.

Answer (score 3):

The value will be 5. Although all parameters are passed by value, in the case of `<? extends Object>` the value of `?` is an address that references the `Object`, so whats is happening when you pass an `Object` is that its address is passes by value. Which means if you use that `Object` its address is the same as the one that got passed, so while you cant assign a `new` `Object` to it you can pretty much do what ever you want with its attributes and this will change the original `Object`'s state.

consider this class example:

```
public class Test {
    public int i;

    public Test(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
}
```

and this static method:

```
public static void changeAtrib(Test t) {
    t.i = 0;
    t = new Test(7);
}
```

now lest create an instance of `Test` and pass it to our method:

```
Test test = new Test(5);
changeAtrib(test);
```

When the method runs the variable `t` inside holds the address value of the original `test`.

The first line in the method is: `t.i = 0;`

Which is referencing `i` using `test`'s original address, that means that `i` will change in the original `test` as well.

Now lets take a look at the second line: `t = new Test(7);`

Now remember `t` holds the address value of `test` and `t = new Test(7);` only creates a new `Test` object and assigns its address to `t`, that operation has no impact on `test` since it only changes the value `t` hold and makes `t` reference a new object.

Comment: how would you do to change test from inside the method? Could it be done changing t?